# Why can I append to an empty table but not set its html via jQuery in IE7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

This problem only occurs using IE (only tested in IE 7, works fine in firefox/chrome).

I've got an empty table element on my page with id='settings'.
After an ajax call executes I place the results of said ajax call into my empty table element like so:

```
$("#settings").html(msg);
```

Well that just isn't working... if I `alert(msg);` I see the html that should be placed into that empty table. The html is valid but for some reason IE7 just isn't rendering it.

I tinkered around for a while and finally tried this:

```
$(msg).appendTo("#settings");
```

Like magic this has some how fixed the issue. Any ideas why the `appendTo()` method would work but not the `html()` method?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you appending it to multiple elements?

Comment: @Nick: Nope, it's only be appended to a single table with id = settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE needs a tbody tag for this to work ;)

Comment: It makes for a correctly formatted table.  The other browsers (in this case) are a bit more forgiving.

Comment: Assuming that your solution does work (I haven't tried it yet because what I did makes it work and I'm being lazy about making any more alterations to it), why? Does appendTo create the <tbody></tbody> tags automatically w/i the empty table tags before appending the msg to it?